# Change countdown timer from date to 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a template with a countdown timer that already has the CSS and formatting I like, however the template currently is setup for a countdown timer using a future date.  I would like to do a simple conversion to a 5 minute countdown timer that starts at 5 minutes each time the page loads.

Here is the current code/logic the site has, any help is MUCH appreciated!!

```
//JUST EDIT Date(2015, 0, 1, 9, 30) 2015 YEAR, 0 MONTH, 1 DATE, 30 SECOND
$('#myCounter').mbComingsoon({expiryDate: new Date(2017, 12, 1, 9, 30), speed: 100});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter takes a Date object of the time when the countdown stops. So in order to get your wanted result, you could create a Date object of 5 minutes from the current time.

```
var countdownDate = new Date(); //create a Date object of current time
countdownDate.setMinutes(countdownDate.getMinutes() + 5); //Add 5 minutes to it
$('#myCounter').mbComingsoon({expiryDate: countdownDate, speed: 100}); //Initialize counter
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you SO much for directly modifying the code so I could copy.paste! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Date` object for the current time. It's already the current time. You may do as follows for 5 minutes;

```js
var insertZero = n => n < 10 ? "0"+n : ""+n,
   displayTime = n => n ? time.textContent = insertZero(~~(n/3600)%3600) + ":" +
                                             insertZero(~~(n/60)%60) + ":" +
                                             insertZero(n%60)
                        : time.textContent = "IGNITION..!",
 countDownFrom = n => (displayTime(n), setTimeout(_ => n ? sid = countDownFrom(--n)
                                                         : displayTime(n), 1000)),
           sid;
countDownFrom(300);
setTimeout(_ => clearTimeout(sid),300000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```